# VB.Net Cannot grab the values on the first form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

I would just like to ask for your help regarding my project as you can see it has a caller instance the other form also has it and it is working (without mathematical operation) but on this form which is form3 which I need a +1 on frm4.label it does not work. (I named it Public Sub New1) Error  1   Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New()(Note: i have another callerinstance on the previous form which is form2 which is named Public SubNew()) and when it run instead of getting the right results the label always shows the text of 0
Please help me thanks in advance happy coding to all :)

```
Public Class Form3
Private frm3 As Form3
Private frm1 As Form1
Private frm4 As Form4

Public Sub New1(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Bread As String, ByVal Cheese As String, ByVal Condiments As String, ByVal Meat As String, ByVal Cost As Decimal, ByVal Quantity As Decimal, ByVal callerInstance As Form1)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm1 = callerInstance
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    frm1 = New Form1(Me)
    frm4 = New Form4()


    If frm4 Is Nothing Then
        frm4 = New Form4
        AddHandler frm4.FormClosed, AddressOf Me.Form4HasBeenClosed

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        i = frm4.Label3.Text
        If TextBox1.Text = frm1.TextBox2.Text Then
            i = +1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1

        ElseIf TextBox2.Text = frm1.TextBox4.Text Then
            i = +1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        ElseIf TextBox3.Text = frm1.TextBox6.Text Then
            i = +1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        ElseIf TextBox4.Text = frm1.TextBox8.Text Then
            i = +1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        ElseIf TextBox5.Text = frm1.TextBox10.Text Then
            i = +1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        ElseIf TextBox6.Text = frm1.TextBox12.Text Then
            i = +1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        ElseIf TextBox7.Text = frm1.TextBox14.Text Then
            i = +1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        ElseIf TextBox8.Text = frm1.TextBox16.Text Then
            i = +1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        ElseIf TextBox9.Text = frm1.TextBox18.Text Then
            i = +1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        ElseIf TextBox10.Text = frm1.TextBox20.Text Then
            i = +1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1

            frm4.Label3.Text = i.ToString()

            frm4.Show()


        Else
            i += 0
            frm4.Show()
        End If
    End If

    If frm4 IsNot Nothing Then
        frm4.Show(Me) 'Show Second Form  
        Me.Hide()
    End If

End Sub
Sub Form4HasBeenClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    frm4 = Nothing
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: how can `frm4` ever be Nothing if you just created it?

Comment: On what line though?  We can't tell where the error is happening from this code sample

Comment: does Form1 have a constructor which takes a Form argument?  I'm not Sure `New1` is what you want.  You can overload New by just having different versions with different arguments.  `New1` wont create a new instance: `Dim frm3 as New1 Form3`

Comment: @Plutonix yes it has and form4 is existing

Comment: @JaredPar Line 16 Column 26 sir thanks :)

Comment: @Plutonix I tried what you have suggested sir and the error changed in to end of statement expected. We are now getting in to somewhere any possible solutions to this sir? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments it sounds like the error is on this line

```
frm1 = new Form1(Me)
```

If that is the case it means that there is no `Sub New` method on `Form1` which accepts a parameter of type `Form3`.  To fix this you need to add one

```
Public Class Form1
  ...
  Public Sub New(ByVal frm3 As Form3)

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: hi sir thanks for your input. But what will I put inside the Public SubNew(ByVal frm3 As Form3) because injecting that code in to the form1 does not changed anything? Thanks

Comment: @user3308511 i really don't know, you'd have to do something similar to what you did in the other form of `New` in `Form1`

Comment: yes sir that is the puzzle here I did not put the New in Form1 I put it in Form2

Comment: @user3308511 you need it in both types

Comment: Hello sir I did it but it commits another error "Cannot accessed due to its protection level"

Comment: @user3308511 make sure u put Public in front of sub New